# How to get clients timezone offset from his ip address

Tags: c#, asp.net, timezone

I want to get clients Time Zone offset from his IP address for my web app. I have tried using Javascripts getTimezone function, but, some clients have their timezone or time set incorrectly. I want to get the offset and render some information back on client based on their timezone.

Thanks for taking time to read the question. I am open for alternate approaches too.

Regards,
Vamyip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can call a web service, you might like to try ipinfodb.com.  For example:

> http://ipinfodb.com/ip_query.php?ip=69.59.196.211&timezone=true

returns:

```
<Response> <Ip>69.59.196.211</Ip> <Status>OK</Status> <CountryCode>US</CountryCode> <CountryName>United States</CountryName> <RegionCode>41</RegionCode> <RegionName>Oregon</RegionName> <City>Corvallis</City> <ZipPostalCode>97333</ZipPostalCode> <Latitude>44.4698</Latitude> <Longitude>-123.343</Longitude> <TimezoneName>America/Los_Angeles</TimezoneName> <Gmtoffset>-25200</Gmtoffset> <Isdst>1</Isdst> </Response>
```

A faster option is to use the free **[MaxMind Geolite city](http://www.maxmind.com/app/geolitecity)**.  If it is not good enough, you can apparently upgrade to a more accurate paid-version.  I can't speak for the quality of the paid version, as I have never used it.  You can [download the file binary blob version](http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz) of the same database, and then use [the C# class](http://www.maxmind.com/app/csharp) to query it.

Comment: ipinfodb.com don't do the TimezoneName any more, just the offset.

Comment: further more, ipinfodb limit the rate of the queries to 2/sec, which is not enough in more than small traffic websites. See "Query Limit" [here](http://ipinfodb.com/ip_location_api.php)

Answer (score -3):

google 'geolocation ip'

There are API's you can call provided by companies.  Some are free, some are not.