# How to get Time Zone through IP Address in JAVA

Tags: java, jsp

I want to get time zone through IP Address in JAVA.

Actually i have an application which will run at the client machine.

I have IP address of client machine. But not able to get the time zone for each client machine.

In client machine

Comment: where you want to get it at server or client?

Comment: The client machine knows its time zone. Why would you want to deduce it from its IP address? What about machines on a LAN, using a private addressing plan (192.168.x.x, for example)?

Comment: Check this [post out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763263/how-to-get-clients-timezone-offset-from-his-ip-address). It is in C# XML version but you may be able to get an idea.

Comment: get it a client zone and send to server, see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For getting timezone through IP Address; there are GeoTimezone where there are certain range of IP that represent a perticuler TIMEZONE and country. You can download that all file that is in CSV and create a database. Then through sql query you can get your timezone.

Answer (score 1):

In Java will give you timezone

```
java.util.TimeZone.getDefault();
```

If you want to get client's time zone at server, then call this at client and send back to server.

Comment: Outdated (as of 2014). Today use `ZoneId.systemDefault()`. It does seem from the question that this is what the OP needs and that they need not go through the IP address for their purpose.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible.
But what can you do is to get the time zone using JavaScript through HTML and then retrieve this data through form submission or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

Use getZoneFromIpAddress(String ip) :

```
    private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
          sb.append((char) cp);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
    
        public String getZoneFormIpAddress(String ip) throws IOException{
          String zone = "inconnu";
          try {
              JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl("https://api.ipdata.co/"+ip+"?api-key=test");
              zone = json.get("country_name")+" "+json.get("city");
          } catch (Exception e) {
          }
          return zone;
    } 
      
        public String getJsonCodeFromUrl(String url) throws IOException{
          JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl(url);
          return json.toString();}
          public String getJsonValueByKey(String url, String key) throws IOException{
          JSONObject json = readJsonFromUrl(url);
          return (String) json.get(key);}


    public static JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {

        InputStream is = new URL(url).openStream();

        try {
          BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
          String jsonText = readAll(rd);
          JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
          return json;
        } finally {
          is.close();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free API from [ip2location.io](https://www.ip2location.io). Just signup for the free plan and you'll get the API key to use with the code below. Change the IP to whichever IP address you wish to query.

```
try (java.util.Scanner s = new java.util.Scanner(new java.net.URL("https://api.ip2location.io/?key=YOUR_API_KEY&ip=8.8.8.8&format=json&lang=en").openStream(), "UTF-8").useDelimiter("\\A")) {
    System.out.println(s.next());
} catch (java.io.IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```