# How can I get timezone by using IP address in Java?

Tags: java, timezone

As described;
Now I want to get timezone by IP address in Java, but I can't find anything really helpful with my ask;
If u have a better way to solve this pls share ur thoughts with me;

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get Time Zone through IP Address in JAVA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13968483/how-to-get-time-zone-through-ip-address-in-java)? Also related: [How to get Time Zone through IP Address in PHP \[duplicate\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/743505/how-to-get-time-zone-through-ip-address-in-php). Search fore more.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the open api

https://ipinfo.io/

This will give you the timezone for the IP address.
But remember, this is public IP address.

Comment: Funnily this link gives me partly different info for my own IP address: https://ipgeolocation.io/timezone-api.html. But the same and correct time zone.

Comment: Yes because the IP address is the public IP which will eventually be very few for a country. So many will be getting same IP info across country using the same ISP in zone.